# how to add an address sanitizer cmake variant to a vscode project

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, cmake

I am using CMake 3.18.4 on a C++ (GCC 10.2.1) project with Visual Studio Code.  I want to include a build variant with the GCC

I have a .vscode/cmake-variants.yaml

```
buildType:
  default: debug
  choices:
    debug:
      short: Debug
      long: Disable optimizations - include debug information
      buildType: Debug
    asan:
      short: Asan
      long: Instrument with Address Sanitizer
      buildType: Asan
```

VSCode uses that to configure CMake like this:

```
[main] Configuring project: example 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Asan -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++ -S/workspaces/example -B/workspaces/example /build -G Ninja
```

What [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-configurations) do I need to add to my CMakeLists.txt such that my build includes `-fsanitize=address` in my compiler and linker options when the Asan build variant is selected.

```
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Asan>:-fsanitize=address>)
add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:Asan>:-fsanitize=address>)
```

Comment: ... I mean..., what's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: When I build with those lines in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, I don't get an asan exception when I do something like `char a[8]; memcpy(a, "12345678\0", 9);`. I also don't see `libasan.*` when I do `ldd myapp`.